# WWW-Authenticate header in Identity Server 4 Unauthorized response

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, identityserver3

I'm protecting a Web API with Identity Server 4.

If an external app tries to access it using client credentials but does not pass in the access token, I get, as expected, the Unauthorized response.

The problem here is that the response does not include the WWW-Authenticate header as I was expecting, as stated in the [OAuth spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3).

Am I missing some config in Identity Server? Or is it something wrong with the Identity Server implementation?

---

The relevant code parts follow:

**Client registration on Identity Server:**

```
new Client()
{
    ClientId = "datalookup.clientcredentials",
    ClientName = "Data Lookup Client with Client Credentials",
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    AllowOfflineAccess = false,
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("XXX".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        Scopes.DataLookup.Monitoring,
        Scopes.DataLookup.VatNumber
    },
    ClientClaimsPrefix = "client-",
    Claims =
    {
        new Claim("subs", "1000")
    }
}
```

**ApiResource registration on Identity Server:**

```
new ApiResource()
{
    Name = "datalookup",
    DisplayName = "Data Lookup Web API",
    ApiSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("XXX".Sha256())
    },
    UserClaims =
    {
        JwtClaimTypes.Name,
        JwtClaimTypes.Email,
        JwtClaimTypes.Profile,
        "user-subs"
    },
    Scopes =
    {
        new Scope()
        {
            Name = Scopes.DataLookup.Monitoring,
            DisplayName = "Access to the monitoring endpoints",
        },
        new Scope()
        {
            Name = Scopes.DataLookup.VatNumber,
            DisplayName = "Access to the VAT Number lookup endpoints",
            Required = true
        }
    }
}
```

**Authentication configuration in the Web API:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    (...)
    services.AddMvc();
    services
        .AddAuthorization(
            (options) =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(
                    Policies.Monitoring,
                    (policy) =>
                    {
                        policy.RequireScope(Policies.Scopes.Monitoring);
                    });
                options.AddPolicy(
                    Policies.VatNumber,
                    (policy) =>
                    {
                        policy.RequireScope(Policies.Scopes.VatNumber);
                        policy.RequireClientSubscription();
                    });
            });
    services.AddAuthorizationHandlers();
    services
        .AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
            (options) =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = "datalookup";
            });
    (...)
}
```

**Client accessing the Web API:**

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    // client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Constants.WebApiEndpoint))
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ConsoleHelper.WriteErrorLine(response);
                return;
            }
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            ConsoleHelper.WriteInformationLine(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that `client.SetBearerToken(accessToken)` is commented, so that is why I was expecting the response to include the WWW-Authenticate header.

The whole idea behind this is to implement a feature on a client library to deal with the Http Bearer challenge (as, for example, the Azure KeyVault client library does).

Comment: Could you add some code please showing the web API end point you are calling and how you are trying to call it.   And what grant type you have created your client on the IDs.    we need a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to be able to test this.

Comment: Thank you for you comment @DaImTo. I've updated the question with the relevant code.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've tried sample projects based on the examples at both https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/apis.html and https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#adding-an-api but with none of them do I get a response with a www-authenticate header set. It looks like you end up in IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler with no scheme to forward the challange to so it calls base.HandleChallengeAsync that just sets the StatusCode to 401.

Comment: Hi @JohanAppelgren. I understand that the Identity Server team has fixed a bug in the AccessTokenValidation library that is supposed to fix this. Before that I have worked around the bug with some custom code. So do check the current version of the library. If the problem is still not solved (I don't know if they already released that bug fix), let me know and I'll send you my custom code.